# expanding factor interactions within a formula

Tags: r

I have many formulas (of class `formula` or `Formula`) of the form `y ~ a*b`, where `a` and `b` are factors.

I need to write a function that takes such a formula and returns a formula with all of the terms in the interaction "spelled out."  Here is an example:

```
fac1 <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))
fac2 <- factor(c('c', 'd', 'c', 'd'))
BigFormula(formula(x ~ fac1*fac2))
```

where `BigFormula` returns `formula(x ~ a + b + c + d + a:c + a:d + b:c + b:d)`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

(The context: I am running many commands of the form `anova(mod1, mod2)`, where `mod2` nests in `mod1`, and where the right-hand side of both models contains terms like `fac1*fac2`.  The point of these commands is to calculate F-statistics.  The problem is that `anova` treats `fac1*fac2` as three variables, even though it usually represents more than three variables.  (In the code above, for example, `fac1*fac2` represents eight variables.)  As a result, `anova` underestimates the number of restrictions in the nested model, and it overestimates my degrees of freedom.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the following solution. I use a more extreme example of a complex interaction.

`f = formula(y ~ a * b * c * d * e)`

To spell out the interaction terms, we extract the terms from the value returned by terms.formula():

`terms = attr(terms.formula(f), "term.labels")`

which yields:

```
> terms
 [1] "a"         "b"         "c"         "d"         "e"         "a:b"       "a:c"      
 [8] "b:c"       "a:d"       "b:d"       "c:d"       "a:e"       "b:e"       "c:e"      
[15] "d:e"       "a:b:c"     "a:b:d"     "a:c:d"     "b:c:d"     "a:b:e"     "a:c:e"    
[22] "b:c:e"     "a:d:e"     "b:d:e"     "c:d:e"     "a:b:c:d"   "a:b:c:e"   "a:b:d:e"  
[29] "a:c:d:e"   "b:c:d:e"   "a:b:c:d:e"
```

And then we can convert it back to a formula:

`f = as.formula(sprintf("y ~ %s", paste(terms, collapse="+")))`

```
> f
y ~ a + b + c + d + e + a:b + a:c + b:c + a:d + b:d + c:d + a:e + 
    b:e + c:e + d:e + a:b:c + a:b:d + a:c:d + b:c:d + a:b:e + 
    a:c:e + b:c:e + a:d:e + b:d:e + c:d:e + a:b:c:d + a:b:c:e + 
    a:b:d:e + a:c:d:e + b:c:d:e + a:b:c:d:e
```

Answer (score 10):

Look at the help for `formula` there may be existing things that will work for you.

For example the formula `y ~ (a + b + c + d)^2` will give you all main effects and all 2 way interactions and the formula `y ~ (a + b) * (c + d)` gives the expansion that you show above.
You can also subtract terms so `y ~ a*b*c - a:b:c` will not include the 3 way interaction.

Answer (score 4):

I still have yet to learn all the tricks of formula, but if I want explicit formulas I'll tend to use sapply along with pasting:

```
# the factors
fac1 <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))
fac2 <- factor(c('c', 'd', 'c', 'd'))

# create all the interaction terms
out <- sapply(levels(fac1), function(ii) {
  sapply(levels(fac2), function(jj) {
    paste0(ii,":",jj)
  })
})
# along with the single terms
terms <- c(levels(fac1), levels(fac2), as.vector(out))

# and create the rhs of the formula
rhs <- paste0(terms, collapse=" + ")

# finally add the lhs
f <- paste0("x ~ ", rhs)
```

We end up with:

```
> f
[1] "x ~ a + b + c + d + a:c + a:d + b:c + b:d"
```

Comment: didn't use it exactly, but it was useful.  Was trying to integrate extended interactions in boruta, and this was a decent starting point.  Ended up brute-force extending the data frame using for loops.  Might have been better to make something in data.table, then set it to data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this solution:

```
  fac1 <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))
  fac2 <- factor(c('c', 'd', 'c', 'd'))
  update(formula(x ~ fac1*fac2),~.)
```

Answer (score -1):

We got similar problem, but bit easier - in formula we got like 50 variables and we had to change them very often; our solution was to within R script send them in a loop to external file making actual formula then simple read that txt file and paste it; as far as I remember it could be done in nested loop as to make more formulas then read back the file line by line;
all in all it is always good to use both R scripts and bash